# Is lumosity.com based on science?

Tags: neuroscience, learning

I always see these Lumosity ads on TV, and I personally feel they are just trying to "sell me something". I did some layman's research ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumosity)) and read that "Studies of Lumosity's effectiveness have shown mixed results".

Does anyone with knowledge on the topic of learning know if the "brain games" they post are simply games? I guess the proper question would be:

Can games like the ones Lumosity offers increase cognitive ability?

Comment: This question on Cognitive Science SE has a couple good answers about this topic: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/how-valid-is-lumositys-brain-performance-index-and-what-normative-information-i

Comment: Most advertisements are trying to "sell you something", namely, the product being advertised.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the purpose of SE Biology is not to make judgement on television programmes or advertisments. This is not therefore a question about biology that allows an objective answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Zickefoose et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23672446) did a study, and showed that while you might improve while playing the game, it called into question if you actually improved outside of just getting better at the game.

[Redick et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22708717) also reported that when they did a double blind study in brain games like Luminosity that you improved in the games, but they didn't see any transfer from game to every-day life.

Also see my previous answer on the topic: [Cognitive Science Forum](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/what-benefit-is-there-to-playing-highly-repetitive-games/10338#10338)

Comment: I figured as much, although only based on personal opinion more than actual data. Thanks

Comment: wow, that's even harsher than I was expecting :O (expected it to at least have some effect, though less than most other/better forms of studying/training/etc.)